# The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot itfoxtec

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I'm using ITFoxtec SAML 2.0 where I have started multiple projects; TestIdpCore and TestWebAppCore. Once I click on the TestWebAppCore login link, I face the error **"The SSL connection could not be established"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the TLS/SSL certificate you are using on the TestIdpCore, which is apparently not accepted by .NET Core.
TestIdpCore espose a SAML 2.0 metadata endpoint which is read by TestWebAppCore as the first step in the login sequence.